# How to insert a variable in a sql query that is a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I can get that query to run perfectly only with a profusion of single quotes around my condition OBZ16. If I try to replace that condition by the variable **@Sym1** I get no results. (No matter how many single quotes and + I put around the variable!)

```
SET @Sym1 = 'OBZ16'
SET @filePath1A = 'C:\Users\Richard\XYZ.xlsx'

SET @sql1A = 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel     12.0;Database=' + @filePath1A + '' + ';' + '''' + ',''SELECT Expiration FROM [WatchList$] WHERE OXSymb = ''''OBZ16'''''''+')' 

EXEC(@sql1A)
```

Comment: `SET @sql1A = 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @filePath1A + '' + ';' + '''' + ',''SELECT Expiration FROM [WatchList$] WHERE OXSymb = ''''' + @Sym1 + ''''''')'` doesn't work?

Comment: Your query, if concatenating in a variable (like + @Sym1), is vulnerable to [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code generates this query:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Users\Richard\XYZ.xlsx;'
,'SELECT Expiration FROM [WatchList$] WHERE OXSymb = ''OBZ16''')
```

Around OBZ16 you have a set of extra quotes that can be removed
To make your code easier to read you should add each quote separately as four single quotes between two plus signs. Then you can see where you have to place the variable. It would look like this:

```
SET @Sym1 = 'OBZ16'
SET @filePath1A = 'C:\Users\Richard\XYZ.xlsx'

SET @sql1A = 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 12.0;Database=' 
+ @filePath1A + ';' + '''' + ',' + '''' + 'SELECT Expiration FROM [WatchList$] WHERE OXSymb = ' + '''' +  @sym1 + '''' + '''' + ')'
```

This code generates the query:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Users\Richard\XYZ.xlsx;'
,'SELECT Expiration FROM [WatchList$] WHERE OXSymb = 'OBZ16'')
```

It is the same query but with only one set of quotes around OBZ16 and the text OBZ16 now comes from the variable @sym1.

Albert

Comment: Albert, Thank you very much for your help, That quotes business drives me crazy. That does not work though I get this answer:
Incorrect syntax near 'OBZ16'. But If I put more quotes! in the variables like this it works:SET @Sym1 = '''OBZ16'''. Thank you again you made my day!